# Beards or no beards

Tags: buddha

I know that there were rules for the Disciples to shave only on the New moon and the Full moon. Did the Buddha follow this practice , too? Or, did Buddha usually have a beard?'

Comment: See also [Hair of the Buddha](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2804/254)

Comment: what's in it for you ?

Comment: Is there anyone who knows about the actual day to day activities of the Buddha, after His Enlightenment? I got one very terse answer and one other that did not really make sense in relationship to my question. Thank you for any and all efforts to answer this actual question. "Did the Buddha cut or trim his head hairs and facial hairs, after His Enlightenment?" Thank you , all.

Answer (score 2):

The Buddha said in MN100:

> [I shaved off my hair and beard, dressed in ocher robes, and went forth from the lay life to homelessness.](https://suttacentral.net/mn100/en/sujato)
>
> There is, however, one clue that the Buddha didn't shave his head
> after his enlightenment. The disciple Upali originally was working as
> a barber when the Buddha came to him for a haircut.

---

O'Brien, Barbara. "[Buddhist Monks and Shaved Heads](https://www.thoughtco.com/why-buddhist-monks-and-nuns-shave-their-heads-449598)" ThoughtCo, Jun. 25, 2018:

> The early scriptures tell us that the Buddha lived in the same way as his disciples. He wore the same robes and begged for food like everyone else. So why isn't the historical Buddha depicted bald, as a monk? (The fat, bald, happy Buddha is a different Buddha.)
>
> The earliest scriptures don't tell us specifically how the Buddha wore his hair, although stories of the Buddha's renunciation tell us he cut his long hair short when he began his quest for enlightenment.
>
> There is, however, one clue that the Buddha didn't shave his head after his enlightenment. The disciple Upali originally was working as a barber when the Buddha came to him for a haircut.

Comment: Please reread the question. I did not ask for that. I asked for actual practices from , day to day , month to month, year to year. Did Buddha shave on those two days?

Comment: see edit pertaining to post-enlightenment

Comment: This was helpful "There is, however, one clue that the Buddha didn't shave his head after his enlightenment. The disciple Upali originally was working as a barber when the Buddha came to him for a haircut." Do you have more information about that event?

Comment: Here, I found this on another website, posted by a Bhikkhu Pesala.

Comment: Hair of the head.
The hair of the head should not be worn long. It should be shaved at least every two months or when the hair has grown to a length of two fingerbreadths — whichever occurs first, says the Commentary. In Thailand there is the custom that all bhikkhus shave their heads on the same day, the day before the full moon, so that the Community can present a uniform appearance. Although this is not obligatory, a bhikkhu who does not follow the custom tends to stand out from his fellows.

Comment: A razor is one of a bhikkhu's eight basic requisites. He is also allowed a whetstone, a razor case, a piece of felt (to wrap the razor in), and all razor accessories (such as a strop). At present, this allowance would cover all types of safety razors as well. The Commentary to Pr 2 insists that the razor case not be multicolored

Comment: Unless ill — e.g., he has a sore on his head — a bhikkhu may not use scissors to cut his hair or have it cut. The question of using electric razors to shave the head is a controversial one. Because their cutting action — even in rotary shavers — is like that of scissors, many Communities will not allow their use in shaving the head.

Comment: You seem to have researched well and found your own answer. You can post your own answer and accept it. :D

Answer (score 0):

The Buddha rebelled against the theistics.

> *141. Neither going about naked, nor **matted dreadlocks (hair)**, nor filth, nor fasting, nor lying on the ground, nor smearing oneself with ashes
>   and dust, nor sitting on the heels (in penance) can purify a mortal
>   who has not overcome doubt.*
>
> *Dhammapada*

[image]